# Cover letter in e-mail body?

Tags: cover-letter

I am applying to a company for an internship and I am wondering whether I should attach my cover letter to the e-mail or just write that as the e-mail body.  I feel that including it in the e-mail body would be the most logical approach however I am not 100% sure on what the standard for this is.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include your cover letter in the body of your email, your recipient is much more likely to read it -- especially for internship positions, in which cover letters are often optional and not necessarily useful to the employer.

Source: my university's career center, conversations with hiring managers

Comment: This is generally true of all attachments or links in emails, not just CVs too.